Calling ToString with own IFormatProvider doesn't work
This is about IFormattable and IFormatProvider. For sure one can achieve a reversed string representation of value 123 otherwise...
Every C# base data type implements the IFormattable interface. So such a data type provides the method
public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider);

which allows according to the Microsoft documentation both:

You can also define your own format strings to support formatting of    your application-defined types.

In addition, you can define your own custom format providers to supply culture-specific, profession-specific, or industry-specific information used in formatting.


From that is should be possible to write:
// Shall produce "321"
string s = 123.ToString("Z", ReverseFormatProvider);

where "Z" is my own format string and ReverseFormatProvider is my own
(custom) format providers.
I followed the ICustomFormatter interface example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icustomformatter?view=net-8.0.
But it uses only String.Format and not ToString directly as Microsoft documentation says for ToString:
You can call the method directly. It is also called automatically by the Convert.ToString(Object) and Convert.ToString(Object, IFormatProvider) methods, and by methods that use the composite formatting feature in the .NET Framework, such as String.Format(String, Object[]), ...
In my ReverseFormatProvider GetFormat always receives NumberFormatInfo as formatType.
And as a consequence ToString("Z", new ReverseFormatProvider()) throws a System.FormatException (unknown format string).
How do I manage to "attach" custom formatting to base data types by means of IFormatProvider?

Please read this and update your question accordingly. Specify exactly what you expect to happen and exactly what does happen when executing the example code.

The documentation for that overload of Int32.ToString describes the second parameter like this: "An object that supplies culture-specific formatting information.". That's not completely clear but it may mean that only culture information from the provided object is used and not custom formatting functionality.

Based on what I see in the docs and Int32.ToString implementation it is impossible to define your own format string/format specifier.
From the How to: Define and Use Custom Numeric Format Providers doc:

.NET gives you extensive control over the string representation of numeric values. It supports the following features for customizing the format of numeric values:

Standard numeric format strings, which provide a predefined set of formats for converting numbers to their string representation. You can use them with any numeric formatting method, such as Decimal.ToString(String), that has a format parameter. For details, see Standard Numeric Format Strings.
Custom numeric format strings, which provide a set of symbols that can be combined to define custom numeric format specifiers. They can also be used with any numeric formatting method, such as Decimal.ToString(String), that has a format parameter. For details, see Custom Numeric Format Strings.
Custom CultureInfo or NumberFormatInfo objects, which define the symbols and format patterns used in displaying the string representations of numeric values. You can use them with any numeric formatting method, such as ToString, that has a provider parameter. Typically, the provider parameter is used to specify culture-specific formatting.


Hence the IFormatProvider (CultureInfo/NumberFormatInfo) is usually responsible for culture-specific information (like delimiters and so on) and will be used if you use one of the predefined formats or build a custom one from predefined set of custom format specifiers.

Thanks for the hint. I didn't know MS published .NET sources. Following you link there's a subordinate clause saying:
The custom numeric format provider can be used only with the string.Format(IFormatProvider, String, Object[]) method. The other overloads of numeric formatting methods (such as ToString) that have a parameter of type IFormatProvider all pass the IFormatProvider.GetFormat implementation a Type object that represents the NumberFormatInfo type.

@vl106 was glad to help! " I didn't know MS published .NET sources" - yes, .NET Core is OOS. You can view sources at github or https://source.dot.net/ (which has navigation)
